# Angular component rendered before API response completed

Tags: javascript, angular, api, angular8

I'm developing an application with angular 8.
I have a parent component (Bid) contains some child components (service1, service2), each child component loading some data dynamically according to data, this data came from an API. I'm calling this API in the parent component (Bid).

**The problem is at some time the controls are rendered before the API is completed so the page appear empty.**

I tried to call the API in ngOnInit() and in constructor() but the result is the same.

component hierarchy is as follows:

RequestDetails ==> Bid ==> (Service1, Service2)

RequestDetails:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public common: CommonService, public bidService: BidsService) {
this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((param) => {
  
  let bidID = param.get('bidId');
  if (bidID != null) {
    this.bidService.setMode('edit');
    this.getRequestDetails(param.get('id')).then(res => this.bidService.fillEditFields(bidID)) // Get fields values
  }
  else{
    this.getRequestDetails(param.get('id'));
    this.bidService.setMode('create');
  }
})}
```

Bid:

```
constructor(public common: CommonService, public bidsService: BidsService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router) {
this.loading = true;
this.bidsService.bidValue.subscribe(p => this.bid = p);
this.bidsService.bidRequestDetails.subscribe(p => this.bidRequestDetails = p);}
```

Bid Html:

```
<app-net-rate-item [isFCL]="isFCL" *ngFor="let container of filterNetRate(getCurrentEditNetRate(),1)"
    [cargoDetailsId]="0" [netRateContainerType]="container.netRateContainerType"
    [netRateContainerTypeId]="container.netRateContainerTypeId" [netRateContainerAmount]="container.netRateAmount"
    (valueChange)="getNetRateValue($event, container.netRateId, 1)" [netRateType]="1" [sourceType]="sourceType"
    [disabled]="sourceType === 1 ? bid.mainService.originOtherExpensePerShipmentMainService.isDisabled : bid.mainService.destinationOtherExpensePerShipmentMainService.isDisabled"
    [required]="(sourceType === 1 ? !bid.mainService.originOtherExpensePerShipmentMainService.isDisabled : !bid.mainService.destinationOtherExpensePerShipmentMainService.isDisabled)"
    [validate]="validateEvent" [value]="container">
  </app-net-rate-item>
```

Comment: add *ngIf for the component or any HTML element you want to display when data is fetched

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-to-child-communication-w2xqc4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @yazan, I edited the post with my Html code, I'm using *ngFor to loop on the result of the API

Comment: you want app-net-rate-item to be displayed when this.bidRequestDetails get the desired value?

Comment: @yazan Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *ngIf to hide/show components or any HTML elements, in your example you have to provide a boolean property to get the current state as follows:

**Bid.ts**

```typescript
    show = false;
    constructor(public common: CommonService, public bidsService: BidsService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.bidsService.bidValue.subscribe(p => this.bid = p);
    this.bidsService.bidRequestDetails.subscribe(p => {
this.bidRequestDetails = p;
this.show = true;  // to update the state
});}
```

**Bid Html:**

```HTML
<div *ngIf='show'>
    <app-net-rate-item [isFCL]="isFCL" *ngFor="let container of filterNetRate(getCurrentEditNetRate(),1)"
        [cargoDetailsId]="0" [netRateContainerType]="container.netRateContainerType"
        [netRateContainerTypeId]="container.netRateContainerTypeId" [netRateContainerAmount]="container.netRateAmount"
        (valueChange)="getNetRateValue($event, container.netRateId, 1)" [netRateType]="1" [sourceType]="sourceType"
        [disabled]="sourceType === 1 ? bid.mainService.originOtherExpensePerShipmentMainService.isDisabled : bid.mainService.destinationOtherExpensePerShipmentMainService.isDisabled"
        [required]="(sourceType === 1 ? !bid.mainService.originOtherExpensePerShipmentMainService.isDisabled : !bid.mainService.destinationOtherExpensePerShipmentMainService.isDisabled)"
        [validate]="validateEvent" [value]="container">
      </app-net-rate-item>
</div>
```

Just to mention you could add **`<ng-container>`** instead of the outside div element since it is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout and Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

or you could use hidden in Bid.Html also:

```HTML
    <app-net-rate-item [hidden]='!show' [isFCL]="isFCL" *ngFor="let container of filterNetRate(getCurrentEditNetRate(),1)"
        [cargoDetailsId]="0" [netRateContainerType]="container.netRateContainerType"
        [netRateContainerTypeId]="container.netRateContainerTypeId" [netRateContainerAmount]="container.netRateAmount"
        (valueChange)="getNetRateValue($event, container.netRateId, 1)" [netRateType]="1" [sourceType]="sourceType"
        [disabled]="sourceType === 1 ? bid.mainService.originOtherExpensePerShipmentMainService.isDisabled : bid.mainService.destinationOtherExpensePerShipmentMainService.isDisabled"
        [required]="(sourceType === 1 ? !bid.mainService.originOtherExpensePerShipmentMainService.isDisabled : !bid.mainService.destinationOtherExpensePerShipmentMainService.isDisabled)"
        [validate]="validateEvent" [value]="container">
      </app-net-rate-item>
```

Comment: When I tried this solution I got this error  "Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with *"

Comment: just add an outer div to contain the <app-net-rate-item>

Comment: Many thanks, it finally works but I had to but the  (*ngIf) in the parent component because I have many child ones.